# rails search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

Now I can search only from videos page, How to add search from any page ot the site?

When I want to search from another controller search doesn't redirect to index

my controllers/videos_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @videos = Video.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per(12)
  end
```

my views/shared/_menu.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag videos_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= search_field_tag :query, params[:query]  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add that partial to any view page on the site (page_name.html.erb file). It will submit to the controller via the routes file.

Anywhere on the site you can add the following to a view:

```
<%= render "shared/menu" %>
```

Comment: I have this file in layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: Sure, that's one way of seeing this form on every page. Does this solve your issue? Or is there a problem I did not understand?

Comment: the problem is that the search is not rendered page